# How to mute Webbrowser in Windows Forms Application?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

What we have:

An `System.Windows.Forms.Webbrowser` where we run an video.
We'd like to mute the Webbrowser WITHOUT muting the whole application.

Is there any way like `webbrowser.mute()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the video is an HTML5 video and you really only want to mute the video, it is actually pretty straight-forward. You just get the element and set it's attribute.

```
        var video = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("video1");
        video.SetAttribute("muted", "true");
```